# MVC5 VB.Net Convert Dictionary(Of String,String) to SelectList type

Tags: .net, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have a simple VB dictionary:

```
Dim MyOptions As New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {{"one", "ONE"}, {"two", "TWO"}, {"three", "THREE"}}
```

And I am trying to convert it to a SelectList type for use in the Html.DropDownList helper that generates the HTML for a select list.

**I've tried this:**

```
Dim list As SelectList = New SelectList(MyOptions, "Key", "Value", "one") ' errors on this line
html.DropDownList("SomeList", list, "Simple List")
```

**Which results in this error:**

> DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name
>   'Key'.

**And I've tried this:**

```
Dim list As SelectList = New SelectList(MyOptions.[Select](Function(x) New With {Key .Value = x.Key, Key .Text = x.Value}), "Value", "Text") ' errors on this line
html.DropDownList("SomeList", list, "Simple List")
```

**Which results in this error:**

> Public member 'Key' on type 'String' not found.

**EDIT**

I obviously simplified the example above,  a little to simple.

Somewhere in my actual code the dictionary(of string, string) is getting converted to KeyValuePair(Of String, Object).

**The actual code:**

In a class I define this public property:

```
Public InputFilters As List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object)) = Nothing ' stores the details of all the added filter types to be rendered
```

and in this same class I have this method:

```
Private Sub _Add(ByVal type As String, ByVal labelText As String, ByVal id As String, ByVal defaultValue As Object, ByVal additionalInputClass As String, ByVal placeholder As String, ByVal arrValues As String(), ByVal dictValues As Dictionary(Of String, String), ByVal checked As Boolean)
        Dim normalizedValues As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
        If dictValues.Count > 0 Then
            For Each key As String In dictValues.Keys
                normalizedValues.Add(key, dictValues(key))
            Next
        End If
        If arrValues.Count > 0 Then
            For Each val As String In arrValues
                normalizedValues.Add(val, val)
            Next
        End If

        Dim d = New Dictionary(Of String, Object) From {
        {"type", type},
        {"labelText", labelText},
        {"id", id},
        {"defaultValue", defaultValue},
        {"additionalInputClass", additionalInputClass},
        {"checked", checked}, {"placeholder", placeholder},
        {"commonInputClass", CommonInputClass},
        {"idPrefix", IdPrefix}}
        d.Add("Values", normalizedValues) ' breakpoint and watch here shows d("Values") as type Dictionary(Of String, String)


        InputFilters.Add(d) ' breakpoint and watch here shows InputFilters(0)("Values") as type KeyValuePair(Of String, Object)
    End Sub
```

Note the comments on the last two lines as this is where the conversion from dictionary to KeyValuePair is happening.

In the razor view page I am doing this:

```
@For Each Filter As Dictionary(Of String, Object) In Model.InputFilters
    @Html.BuildFilterInput(Filter)
Next
```

And the HTML helper code for BuildFilterInput looks like this:

```
<Extension()>
    Public Function BuildFilterInput(ByVal html As HtmlHelper, ByVal Filter As Dictionary(Of String, Object)) As IHtmlString

        Dim id As String = (Filter("idPrefix") & Filter("id")).ToString()

        Dim Result As String = ""
        Result &= "<div class=""col-md-6 col-lg-4 report-filter-item-wrapper"">" & vbCrLf
        Result &= "   <div class=""form-group"">" & vbCrLf
        Result &= "      " & html.Label(id, Filter("labelText").ToString).ToString() & vbCrLf
        Result &= "      "
        Select Case Filter("type")
            Case "text"
                Result &= html.TextBox(id, Filter("defaultValue").ToString(), New With {Key .name = id, Key .[class] = "form-control" & If(Filter("additionalInputClass").ToString = "", "", " " & Filter("additionalInputClass").ToString()) & If(Filter("commonInputClass").ToString() = "", "", " " & Filter("commonInputClass").ToString()), Key .placeholder = If(Filter("placeholder").ToString() = "", "", Filter("placeholder").ToString())}).ToString() & vbCrLf
            Case "select"
                Dim list As SelectList = New SelectList(Filter.Values, "Key", "Value", "ME") ' this is where it blows up because Filter.Values is not a dictionary !!!!!!
                Result &= html.DropDownList(id, list, "What is this").ToString() & vbCrLf

        End Select
        Result &= "   </div>" & vbCrLf
        Result &= "</div>" & vbCrLf
        Return html.Raw(Result)
    End Function
```

Comment: Your first attempt worked for me.

Comment: Both error messages strongly suggest that `MyOptions` is a string by the time you hit the `html.DropDownList` call. A guess: somewhere along the way you're defining another variable named `MyOptions` as type `String`, and that's the one in scope when you call `html.DropDownList`. Or somehow `MyOptions` is being coerced to a string. Try putting a breakpoint on `MyOptions` and stepping through (hard to do I know with MVC) to see where it's changing, or just visually trace the code to see if that's happening.

Comment: @N0Alias - I see it works for me too whereas my actual code does not. I edited my question with more details

Comment: @EdGibbs - I added additional detail to my question showing the actual code and what the debug watch point values are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DOH!  It's a Syntax Error**

I was using Filter.Values in an attempt to access the "Values" key and I should have been using Filter("Values").